# Is it possible to get the Marshal badge after being privileged with "cast close and reopen votes"

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, flag-badges

When you get to a reputation of 3000 you earn the privilege to cast close votes. According to the help pages, you're not supposed to raise a flag anymore when you get this privilege, but to just vote for closing a question.

It means that basically, I can't get the Marshal badge, although, considering my work on the close-reviews queue, I'm more entitled to it than before.

Is there a reason to ever raise a flag once you reached 3000? Is there a way to get the badge?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can still get the Marshal badge after getting Close Vote privileges.  There are other ways to flag that are outside of close flags.

I previously outlined some of this on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172072/i-dont-flag-what-is-wrong-with-me/172075#172075), but here are some other ways.

Answers can be flagged for a variety of reasons.  You'll see a flag link under each answer which will bring up the dialog:

[image]

Here you can flag an answer as "Not An Answer" - these would be answers that should be comments, or are "Thank this worked" answers or even new questions that have been incorrectly posted as an answer.

You can also raise "Other" flags on questions/answers that might need moderator attention that cannot be handled by the community.  These types of flags go into the moderator queue for review.

There are many things that can be flagged which will help you get the Marshal badge.

Comment: I'd say that for the most prolific flaggers on the site, almost all of their flags were on things other than questions to be closed. Queries like the ones described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/what-are-the-best-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-flagged-or-edited can find residual non-answers to be removed (be careful to actually read the answers and not blindly flag everything from a query, though). The Late Answers and First Posts queues contain many instances of spam that try to work their way into the system. It's easy to rack up this badge just from these.

Comment: @BradLarson I'm ashamed to say I've never seen that meta post before today. I hunted down my flags in different ways.  That just goes to show there are many, many ways to accumulate flags.

Answer (score 10):

You can flag posts for more things than just being off-topic.

If you flag spam, offensive posts, flag answers that are not answers (but new questions or comments, etc), or find sock puppets and use the *other* option to inform a moderator, etc. etc. etc. you also earn helpful flags.

But do remember the badge is there as a nice extra reward for having done a good job, *not the goal itself*.

Answer (score 5):

And of course there are Comment flags (obsolete, etc.) that also count towards "helpful flags"...