# Is flagging a question the same as voting to close?

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close

Is there a difference between flagging a question and voting to close?

In my profile, my suggested next badge is **Deputy**. To achieve it I must:

> Raise 80 helpful flags

I just gained access to close-voting and I noticed that there is some overlap between casting a Close Vote and flagging a question. I voted to close questions and this votes were accepted, but the **Deputy** progress bar does not seem to advance.

Also when I flag as duplicate, for example, my flag is turned into a close vote.

Does this mean that there are some flags for me that now are votes?

Which flags are only flags and which ones turn into close votes?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253617/is-it-possible-to-get-the-marshal-flag-after-being-privileged-with-the-cast-clo?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. If you have the priveledge to cast close votes, you can no longer flag questions for closure. So anything in the "should be closed..." branch of the flag dialog will silently transform into a close vote.

Flags are only used for things that you don't have the ability to handle yourself -- so now you can directly cast close votes there is no need for you a flag.

Comment: That's not quite correct. Use up the close-votes, and you will have to fall back to flags.

Comment: @Deduplicator I just tested this at Programmers, there's no fallback: picking respective close option through flag dialog ends with error message "you have no close votes"

Comment: @gnat: Hmpf. I thought flagging would be possible then, but if you just tested that...